# Can't open IRM protected document in office applications and office web apps

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps, office-integration, irm

I'm using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise with Office Web Apps 2013 and Information Rights Management Configured. (All of our servers are on-prem including the ADRMS)

I have two universal distribution groups that I have users assigned to.

SharePoint-RMSReadOnly
SharePoint-RMSEdit

I am unable to open IRM protected documents from sharepoint in Office Web Apps or the associated Office Applications.

When I open the document in Office Web Apps I get the following errro

```
Sorry, Word Web App can't open this document because it's protected by Information Rights Management (IRM). To view this document please open it in Microsoft Word.
```

When click "Open in Word" I'm prompted for my domain credentials. I enter my credentials and receive this error/prompt.

```
This content could not be accessed using your current credentials do you want to use your microsoft account to access this content?
```

The Permissions on the document I'm testing with I have the Read Only distro group in the Read Only section and the Edit distro group in the Edit section.

I've tried using accounts from both groups to access the document, but receive the same errors on both. I've also read that you should be able to access IRM documents through Office Web Apps in Read-Only Mode.

How do I configure IRM so I can access IRM Protected documents in Office Web Apps and Office Applications?

Comment: Have you validated the service is healthy and working as expected outside of SharePoint?  Check that the SharePoint servers have been added to the ADRMS certification pipeline.

Comment: @JesusShelby On the ServerCertification.asmx I have All the SharePoint Services Accounts, The SharePoint Server (computername$) and they AD RMS Service Group with Read & Execute and Read privileges

Comment: can you also test ADRMS without SharePoint and validate it's working correctly?  Don't just test against groups - also test against individual accounts.

Comment: @JesusShelby Ok, I Disabed IRM on the Farm and on the library I'm testing. Using normal ADRMS Template I was able to protect a document. and have the assigned user access it.

Comment: @JesusShelby I'm able to open documents on accounts the have download permissions on sharepoint, but I'm still unable to open docs in the Office Web App as Read-Only